# Getting feature coordinates from dynamically loaded layer using OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, layers, vector

i want to load the coordinates of a point that is stored inside a vector layer and the vector layer is stored inside a layergroup.
I do load the vector layers dynamically to the layergroup "Runs". So i can't just do:

```
var source = layer.getSource();
source.forEachFeature(function(feature){
  var coord = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
  // ...
});
```

At the moment it is totally unclear how to filter for the layer and then for the point by name to get the coordinates.

So what i have available is the layer name, layergroup name and the feature name. I tried different approaches like:

My layergroup is called 'runs' so to get the layers inside runs i did:

i tried also:

```
runs.getLayers().getSource();
```

But i get:

> Uncaught TypeError: runs.getLayers(...).getSource is not a function.

I'm having a hard time to get my head around this.

---

So i made it a little furhter:

```
      function getActiveLayer(layerName,picID) {
            // get layerGroups
            var layers = map.getLayers();
            var length = layers.getLength(), l;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                l = layers.item(i);
                var lt = l.get('title');
                // check for layers within groups
                if (lt === 'Runs') { // Title of Group
                  // get layers from Runs
                  var layers = l.getLayers();
                  //get length
                  var length = layers.getLength(), l;
                  if (length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

                      l = layers.item(i);
                      var lt = l.get('title');
                      // check for Layer Title
                      if (lt === layerName) { // Title if Layer
                        var innerLayers = l.getSource().getFeatureById(picID).getGeometry().getCoordinates();
                        return innerLayers;
                      }
                    }
            }
                }
            }


      };
```

With this function i get the LayerGroup list that i can parse and identify the Group "Runs" i want. Until this point it is working.

The Problem starts at the second Point. The layers.getLength() is always zero for the layers that are inside the "Runs" Group.
[image]

The Upper one is the getLayers from map.
The lower one is the getLauers from "Runs".

Why is length 0 if there are Layers inside the array?

**EDIT**

```
      function getActiveLayer(layerName,picID) {
        var layers = map.getLayers();
        console.log(layers);
            var length = layers.getLength(), l;
            console.log(length);
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                l = layers.item(i);
                var lt = l.get('title');
                // check for layers within groups
                if (lt === 'Runs') { // Title of Group
                  var layers = l.getLayers().getArray();
                  console.log(layers);
                  //if (length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < 99; i++) {

                      l = layers[i];
                      console.log(l);
                      console.log(layerName);
                      var lt = l.get('title');
                      console.log(lt);
                      // check for Layer Title
                      if (lt === layerName) { // Title if Layer
                        var innerLayers = l.getSource().getFeatureById(picID).getGeometry().getCoordinates();
                        return innerLayers;
                      }
                    }
                }
            }


      };
```

This function works. The only Problem i have that i can not figure out how the get the length of the object to config the second for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone else is starting with openlayes. This is a working function i came up with:

```
 function setActivePicMarker(layerName,layerTitle, featureName) {
   var layers = map.getLayers();
   var length = layers.getLength();
   for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
       l = layers.item(i);
       var lt = l.get('title');

       // check for layers within groups
       if (lt === layerTitle) { // Title of Group
         var layers = l.getLayers().getArray();
         var length = l.getLayers().getArray().length;

           // loop over layers
           for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
             l = layers[i];
             var lt = l.get('title');

             // check for Layer Title
             if (lt === layerName) { // Title if Layer
               var coords = l.getSource().forEachFeature(function (feature){

                    // check for feature and get coordinates
                    if (feature.get('Name') == featureName{
                       var Coords = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
                       console.log(Coords);
                    }    
               })
               return Coords;
             }
           }
       }
   }
}; // end
```

The function searches for a specified feature inside a specified layer inside a specified layer group and returns the features coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I was spacing out at work today... So here is a way of doing what you described above. There are for sure other ways of doing this.

```js
// OpenLayers V4.6.5
// demo data
const feature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point([3,5]), 
  name: 'myFeatureName'
});
feature.setId(5);

const map = new ol.Map({
  view: new ol.View({}),
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Group({
      title: 'Runs',
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Vector({
          title: 'layerName',
          source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [feature]
          })
        })
      ]
    })
  ]
});

//// Return data by Feature ID
// Internal function for returning coordinates from a layer, from a feature by featureID
const byFeatureId = (layer, layerName, picID) => {
  if(layer.get('title') === layerName) {
    return layer.getSource().getFeatureById(picID).getGeometry().getCoordinates();
  }
};

// Public function for returning coordinates from a feature by featureID
// layerName: string, the name of the layer that will be querried
// picID: string/number, the featureID of the feature that will be querried
// groupLayerName: string, 'Runs'
function getCoordinatesByFeatureID(layerName, picID, groupLayerName) {
  var result = [];

  map.getLayers().forEach(groupLayer => {
    if (groupLayer.get('title') === groupLayerName) {
      groupLayer.getLayers().getArray().forEach(innerLayer => {
        result = byFeatureId(innerLayer, layerName, picID);
      });
    }
  });

  return result;
}

console.log('coodinatesById', getCoordinatesByFeatureID('layerName', 5, 'Runs'));

//// Return data by Feature NAME
// Internal function for returning coordinates from a layer, from a feature by featureName
const byFeatureName = (layer, layerName, featureName) => {
  var result = new ol.Feature();

  if(layer.get('title') === layerName) {
    layer.getSource().getFeatures().forEach(feature => {
      if (feature.get('name') === featureName) {
        result = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
      }
    });
  }

  return result;
};

// Public function for returning coordinates from a feature by featureName
// layerName: string, the name of the layer that will be querried
// featureName: string, the featureName of the feature that will be querried
// groupLayerName: string, 'Runs'
function getCoordinatesByFeatureName(layerName, featureName, groupLayerName) {
  var coordinates = [];

  map.getLayers().forEach(groupLayer => {
    if (groupLayer.get('title') === groupLayerName) {
      groupLayer.getLayers().getArray().forEach(innerLayer => {
        coordinates = byFeatureName(innerLayer, layerName, featureName);
      });
    }
  });

  return coordinates;
}

console.log('coodinatesByName', getCoordinatesByFeatureName('layerName', 'myFeatureName', 'Runs'));
```